# XML Error with &amp;

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, cdata

im editing an XML parser and i have a problem; the website has an & in it and i cannot solve it.

I tried this and didnt work:

```
$text=preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $text);
```

This is the line:

```
$dom = DOMDocument::load('https://www.bet-at-home.com/en/feed/sport?sportID=5&username=yyy&password=xxx');
```

I do not know how to use CDATA, which seems to be the only solution.

This is the error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: xmlParseEntityRef: no name in https://www.bet-at-home.com/en/feed/sport?sportID=5&username=yyy&password=xxx, line: 21 in /home/public_html/bet/cronload.php on line 13
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

THIS WAS THE SOLUTION:

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.bet-at-home.com/en/feed/sport?sportID=1&username=xxx&password=yyy');
$dom = DOMDocument::loadXML($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

**That's only warning, not the error.**

You have that warning, because you didn't use variable `$text`, but entered the clean text... Try following code:

```
$text = 'https://www.bet-at-home.com/en/feed/sport?sportID=5&username=yyy&password=xxx';
$text=preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $text);
$dom = DOMDocument::load($text);
```

Comment: This is what i get:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/public_html/bet/cronload.php on line 15

Comment: @ErepublikGold Sorry, forgotten semicolon :-) Try now please

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: xmlParseEntityRef: no name in https://www.bet-at-home.com/en/feed/sport?sportID=5&amp;username=xxx&amp;password=yyy, line: 21

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: xmlParseEntityRef: no name in https://www.bet-at-home.com/en/feed/sport?sportID=5&amp;username=xxx&amp;password=yyy, line: 21 in /home/public_html/bet/cronload.php on line 16

Comment: yep it is!
if (!@mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8");
}

Comment: I've always had utf-8 :/